# Break while loop with UIButton Press in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, asynchronous, while-loop

I'm simulating a 2 player Simon Says game in Xcode 7.1 using Swift. I'm having a hard time understanding how to make things happen asynchronously or using threads, so I thought I was being smart working around it using a while loop that uses a boolean which is changed from false to true when a button is pressed allowing the code to continue on. However, this has proved to not only be incredibly wrong but intuitively probably very inefficient.

A buttons action looks like:

```
@IBAction func P1RedButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    P1RedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    hasSelectedP1 = true;
    selectP1 = 1
}
```

The method used to play what I'm calling the cycle which is simply the round where the user's memory is tested to recall what the buttons had shown during playback.

```
func playCycle(){

        gameOver = false
        var index = 0
        var turn = 1

        while(!gameOver && index < plays){
            if(turn == 1){
                print("Player 1's turn")
                while(!hasSelectedP1){
                   //basically nothing happens here
                   //this runs until user selects a button ( or should )
                }
                if(sequence[index] != selectP1){
                    gameOver = true
                    print("game over because p1")
                }
                turn += 1
            }else{
                print("Player 2's turn")
                while(!hasSelectedP2){
                    //same as above
                }
                if(sequence[index] != selectP2){
                    gameOver = true
                    print("game over because p2")
                }
                turn -= 1
            }
            index += 1
        }
        if(gameOver){
            //reward points to winner
            //quit game
        }
        cycle += 1
        cycleBegin()     // this method is to start "presenting" pattern to memorize
    }
```

The sequence is an array consisting of 100 random numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) representing red, yellow, green, blue respectively.

What is the best way to basically halt the program from executing until the button is pushed instead of using a while loop?

Comment: What a great beginner coding question. Reminds me of how it was for me 30 years ago! As you have suspected, threads would solve your problem. The code inside your while(...) loop could be moved into a thread - see [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: ] or could be simply called repeatedly from NSTimer. Have fun...

Comment: Why is a while loop needed at all? Why not trigger actions on button presses?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to happen, but I don't think it requires halting the program or using whiles or multi-threading.